# How to cast 10 bit sign integer to 16 bit integer in C

Tags: c, casting, bit, bit-shift

I am parsing a data which is a 10 bit signed integer. Since the only way to represent this data is to either use int or short ( for sign 2-byte representation), I have to cast 10 bit to 16 bit.
I have applied 2 methods already but they are either slow or compiler depended.

The slow method is to use `pow()` function

```
value = pow(2,16) - pow(2,10) + value
```

The compiler dependent method is

```
 value = (value << 6) >> 6 (right shift shifts the MSB which is a compiler dependent operation and may shift 0 if compiler is different)
```

Can someone help me find the standar way of casting non standard types to standard types

Comment: Your idea is good. A detail is, that integer expressions are computed in machine-ints. Your expression (value <<6) is **not** a 16 bit expression. It is an integer-expression. (see integer promotion)

Comment: all modern compilers use arithmetic right shift on signed types, so practically there should be no problem using the second way

Comment: Pow is slow and wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic for the operations explicitly written out. Obviously you can do this with a one-liner, but I hope this explains *why*.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {   
    //int16_t  value = 0x3fdb; // random examples
    //int16_t  value = 0x00f3;
    int16_t  value = 0x3f3;
    printf("0x%04x (%i)\n", value, value); // in
    uint16_t mask  = 0x3ff; // 0000 0011 1111 1111 in binary
    uint16_t masked = value & mask; // get only the 10 LSB
    uint16_t extension = (0x200 & value) ? 0xFC00 : 0x0; // extend with 1s or 0s
    printf("extension: %i\n", (extension)?1:0);
    int16_t  extended = extension | masked; // do the extension
    printf("0x%04x (%i)\n", extended, extended); // out

    return 0;
}
```

Examples:

```
0x00f3 (243)
extension: 0
0x00f3 (243)

0x3fdb (16347)
extension: 1
0xffffffdb (-37)

0xfffffff3 (-13)
extension: 1
0xfffffff3 (-13)

0x03f3 (1011)
extension: 1
0xfffffff3 (-13)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value = value & 0x03FF; //mask off the high 6 bits like you want.
```

There should be no 10 bit integers, i assume value is a short but you should add that relevant info.

*edit*
If you only want to mask if the 10th bit is set then:

```
value = (value & 0x0200) ? (value & 0x03FF) : value;
```

Comment: I have mentioned I am parsing a data, where I have a 10-bit number,(the value is actually first read as 16 bit but from the user-specified document the 10 bits represent a different parameter and 6 bits represent differently.
You approach is not correct as it will always mask the last 6 bits with 1s but this is not what I am seeking, I want to mask the bits only if the 10th bit is 1

Comment: The 10-bit value is signed and 2's Complement sign extension requires the extended bits to equal the MSB, not 0.

Comment: @AzizUrRehman the high 6 bits will be set to 0 with this mask.  I'll add the conditional masking that you mentioned

Comment: As @LegendofPedro mentioned I am looking for 2's complement sing extension.I have solved my problem by replacing 0x03FF with 0xFC00